# Can't pip install package from github in virtual environment

Tags: python, github, pip, virtual-environment

I have written a python package `package` which is hosted on github and I would like to install it in a new virtual environment on my pc. It is the simplest package possible:

```
package
├── README.md
├── pkg
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── setup.py
```

I tried to install it using the following lines

```
(my_venv) C:\venv\my_venv>pip install git+https://github.com/MyUsername/package.git
```

But it installed itself in the following path, where things are installed when you use no venv,

`c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages`
instead of
`c:\venv\my_venv`.

What should I do to correct this and install the package **inside** the virtual environment?

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip` instead? Worth a shot

Comment: pip might not be pointing to the python interpreter in the venv

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `python -m pip` to make it use the pip within your environment. Using pip without the `-m` flag might be pointing it to the global pip install.